# Dans l'informatique, entend/voit-on plus souvent "assurance qualité" ou "contrôle de qualité" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, informatique

Je parle bien sûr de "QA," ou "Quality Assurance" en anglais - c'est à dire le processus de trouver et corriger des bugs chez les entreprises de logiciel.

Jusqu'alors je vois les deux termes mentionnés dans la question. Une recherche rapide sur Google me dit que "assurance qualité" apparait plus souvent, mais est-ce vrai ? Existe-t-il peut-être une autre option plus courante ?

Comment: J'ai souvent entendu parlé de Plan Qualité... qualifié de PQ quand il était mal ficelé.

Comment: "Assurance qualité" me fait plus penser à une assurance décès... alors que "contrôle qualité" me paraît beaucoup plus naturel

Comment: J'ai également entendu "Plan qualité" (le document qui définit les règles de la qualité). Et nous parlions de "qualité" tout court, par exemple "s'occuper de la qualité", "responsable [de la] qualité", ou "audit qualité".

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas vraiement un problème de langue : le [contrôle qualité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contr%C3%B4le_qualit%C3%A9) et l'[assurance qualité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assurance_qualit%C3%A9) sont deux processus différents. En deux mots, le contrôle qualité est la manière historique de procéder, qui consiste à vérifier a posteriori qu'un produit est conforme aux exigences de qualité. L'assurance qualité est une démarche plus globale, qui englobe le contrôle qualité. Elle consiste à mettre en oeuvre des procédures documentées et auditables pour s'assurer que le produit sera conforme aux exigences de qualité.

Answer (score 0):

Si j'ai bien compris :

On cherche à transcrire le processus d'évaluation de la qualité d'un produit, c'est à dire le respect du cahier des charges ou des référentiels qui déterminent ce produit.

J'ai déjà entendu **assurance qualité**, mais à mes oreilles me semble ambigü (précisément parce que ce n'est pas une assurance au sens *contrat d'assurance*, mais contrôle pour s'*assurer* de la bonne qualité du produit).
Il me semble qu'on parle alors d'**audit qualité**.

Aucun de ces termes n'est restreint aux logiciels.